# Invariant measure on a vector space descends to a finite measure on the quotient modulo lattice

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $V$ be a real vector space of finite dimension $n$ endowed with an invariant measure $\mu$. Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $V$. I wonder how and why $\mu$ induces a finite measure on $V/\Gamma$.

This is from Serre's a course in arithmetic, page 106-107.

I understand that if $V:=\mathbb R^n$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure then $\mathbb R^n/ \Gamma$ is a high dimensional torus whose measure should be identified with the measure of a fundamental domain in $\mathbb R^n$.

However, here $\mu$ is just an invariant measure (invariant to translation I guess) and I have no idea how $\mu$ descends to a finite measure on $V/\Gamma$.

Comment: By theorem of H'aar there is only one invariant measure on $V$ up to scaling.
Actually this is true for any second countable locally compact group.

Comment: @Sheve You mean the uniqueness of Haar measure? I think the definition of Haar measure involves not only translation invariance, but also finiteness on compact set and inner and outer regularity...

Comment: Yes i mean the Haar measure. You are correct, the definition of Haar measure involves inner and outer regularity but in the case the space is second countable and locally compact assuming that the invariant measure is on the Borel sigma algebra then it is turns out to be a regular measure.

Comment: @Sheve Thanks! Is it also finite on compact sets automatically?

Comment: You can always take a measure that is infinite on any set... But otherwise once you have a set with finite measure then that is enough.

Comment: @Sheve Say I have a nonempty set $A$ with finite measure, then how do I conclude that every compact subset has finite measure?

Comment: Since is Inf of open sets and it is a finite, this means that there is a open set $U$ with finite measure, by invariance- $0\in U$.  Take any compact set $K$ we show this means it measure is not infinite, this is since $K\subset \cup_{k\in K}(k+U)$ by compactness we have finite union thus $\mu(K)\le n \cdot\mu(U)$.